# Theory of the von Neumann hierarchy

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, set-theory, ordinals, axioms

The sets $V_\alpha$ in the cumulative von Neumann hierarchy, defined by transfinite induction:

$\begin{align}
V_0 &= \varnothing \\
V_{\alpha+1} &= \mathcal{P}(V_\alpha) \\
V_\lambda &= \bigcup_{\beta < \lambda} V_\beta \quad \text{for limit ordinals } \lambda.
\end{align}$

are known to be models of the various axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ for various values of $\alpha$. (E.g. $\alpha > \omega$ limit $\implies V_\alpha \vDash \mathsf{ZFC}$ minus replacement, $\kappa$ strongly inaccessible $\implies V_\kappa \vDash \mathsf{ZFC}$).

What do the $V_\alpha$ say about the various alternative axioms for set theory / statements independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$ (e.g. $\mathsf{AC}, \mathsf{AD}, \mathsf{CH}, \mathsf{GCH}, \mathsf{V\!=\!L}$, Martin's axioms, large cardinal axioms, forcing axioms, etc), for various values of $\alpha$?

Comment: There are a lot of small questions, which can be answered easily by understanding the reflection theorem, and analyzing local statements (AD, CH, etc.) vs. global statements, and how they interact with reflection.

Comment: Note that the $V_n, n < \omega,$ have nothing to say about CH, but that CH is decided by stage $V_{\omega + 3}$, and then all higher $V_{\alpha}$ agree on its decision.

Comment: The answers for some of these axioms can depend on the details of how the axiom is formulated. For example, AC can be stated as "for every family of pairwise disjoint nonempty sets there is a set intersecting each of them exactly once" or as "every family of nonempty sets admits a choice function." The former seems to be true in every $V_\alpha$, while the latter needs $\alpha$ to be a limit ordinal, because of the ordered pairs needed in the function. (And "every set is in bijection with a (von Neumann" ordinal" holds even more rarely.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass this seems to be one of those rare and annoying moments where the implementation details matter and using a flat pairing function might be worth it

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I agree, and I'll add that your comment reinforces mine. Even if one decide to formulate AC in terms of choice functions, the specific pairing functions that one uses can affect whether it's true in certain $V_\alpha$'s.

Comment: @Andreas: So if I insist that $(a,b)$ is coded as $\{\kappa,\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ for $\kappa$ being the first $\kappa$th fixed point of both $\aleph$ and $\beth$ functions that is itself the limit of $\kappa$ many $\alpha$s that are $\aleph$ and $\beth$ fixed points, then until I go very very high up the hierarchy, the axiom of choice is false due to a lack of functions (and also we cannot develop analysis, etc. for the same reason.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila You'll have to go very high in the hierarchy to get that form of AC to hold. You could still develop analysis in lower levels by using "Andreas's cheap imitation functions" that omit the magnificent $\kappa$ from the ordered pairs.

Comment: @Andreas: Sounds like copyright infringement to me.